# wordpress plugin - how to change the post date time?

Tags: plugins, wordpress

I have a plugin that I need to change the post date time. What WP function should I use to do this?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would want to use `wp_update_post($post)` with a new `post_date` value - http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_post

```
$mypost = array();
$mypost['ID'] = 111; // the post ID you want to update
$mypost['post_date'] = $your_date; // uses 'Y-m-d H:i:s' format
wp_update_post($mypost);
```