# how to edit wordpress page from backend

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, edit

i have created a plugin that creates a page on activation. 
now i cant find a way to update the content of the page programitically
i have been searching the internet for a while could not find an answer
here is how i create a new page using my plugin

```
function some_function()
{
   $post_details = array(
      'post_title'    => 'Page title',
      'post_content'  => 'Content of your page',
      'post_status'   => 'publish',
      'post_author'   => 1,
      'post_type'     => 'page'
   );
   wp_insert_post( $post_details );
}
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'some_function');
```

Comment: Did you take a look at Wordpress docs? The page for `wp_insert_post` show a related function called `wp_update_post` that links here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_post

Comment: possible duplicate of [wordpress plugin - how to change the post date time?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13114270/wordpress-plugin-how-to-change-the-post-date-time)