# How to update post publish date time on click wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

so i need to make button or link which will update post publish date.

i found this but i dont know how to call it.

```
$time = current_time('mysql');

wp_update_post(
    array (
        'ID'            => $id,
        'post_date'     => $time,
        'post_date_gmt' => get_gmt_from_date( $time )
    )
);
```

Comment: You can check [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13114270/wordpress-plugin-how-to-change-the-post-date-time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13114270/wordpress-plugin-how-to-change-the-post-date-time) as your issue is similar to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this:

```
$mypost = array();
$mypost['ID'] = 1; // the post ID you want to update
$mypost['post_date'] = $your_date; // uses 'Y-m-d H:i:s' format
wp_update_post($mypost);
```

Hope this helps..